# Forming a Map from two HashSets while maintaining the same key,value mapping indeterminate of order

Tags: java, dictionary, set

I have 2 hash sets to be combined into a map with **Set 1** being the key. How can I ensure that a particular item in set 2 is **always** mapped to it's corresponding item in set 1 when either sets order is changed?.
 
For example:

[image: Example]

Would I be better off using TreeSets initially (considering that the insertion order will also be different), so I can be sure of where the particular values that I want to 'link' are, even though this is more difficult computationally? Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: How do you define "corresponding item"?

Comment: Why does the order of the sets matter? As long as you maintain the link from the key to the value. It doesn't matter how the keys or values shuffle.

Comment: If the order of elements in your sets is meaningful, then `HashSet` is the wrong implementation. You want a `TreeSet`, a `LinkedHashSet`, or some other implementation that preserves order.

Comment: Defining corresponding item as Set1A has to **always** map to Set2A

Comment: @BOND The link has not been established yet!, that is why I want to create the Map, for all intensive purposes, Set1 and Set2 are just random sets with no relation until the Map occurs.

Comment: So what maps Set1 to Set 2, and why would you not just put them into an actual map at that point and ensure the relationship?

Comment: This question sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).